# How to convert byte array to IFormFile in C# .NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I need to know how to convert byte[] to IFormFile in C#, .NET CORE
Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: this seems like XY problem - but simply you can't - as it doesn't make sens

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'd recommend taking [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and then reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as an introduction to how SO works, and how to effectively ask a question.

Answer (score 3):

The source code [FromFile.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Http/Http/src/FormFile.cs) shows it implements the **IFromFile** interface. Although you can easily find those files from `HttpRequest.Form.Files` property if dealing with a http request, you still can create a custom **IFromFile** object via a local file or via a byte array which you already have. An example like this, hope helps.

UnitTest.cs

```cs
[Fact]
public async Task FileUploadToStorage_ReturnTrue_Test()
{
    var testFilePath = "path/to/test.jpg";
    var testFileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(testFilePath);
    var service = new FakeStorageService();
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(testFileBytes))
    {
        IFormFile fromFile = new FormFile(ms, 0, ms.Length,
            Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(testFilePath),
            Path.GetFileName(testFilePath)
        );

        var result = await service.Upload(fromFile);
        Assert.True(result);
    }
}
```

FakeStorageService.cs

```cs
public class FakeStorageService
{
    public async Task<bool> Upload(IFormFile file)
    {
        using (var fs = file.OpenReadStream())
        {
            return await GetStorage().UploadAsync(fs);
        }
    }
}
```